# reledmac, bibleref entry in footnoteA and line number in Index

Tags: footnotes, indexing, reledmac, bibleref

When I have bibleref in \Xfootnote and use index, in index entry appears line number of the footnote.
I'd prefer instead of line number of footnote would be line number what footnote refers. Or footnote number (this seems harder, right?)

Here  is MWE:

```
        \documentclass[twoside,14pt,onecolumn,openright ,a4paper]{memoir}
        \usepackage{lipsum}
        %\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
        \usepackage{fontspec}
        \usepackage[english]{babel}
        \usepackage{xunicode}
        \usepackage[nonewpage]{indextools}
        % \usepackage[xindy,splitindex,nonewpage]{indextools}
        \usepackage[series={A,B,C,D,E}]{reledmac}
        %\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}
        \usepackage{perpage}
        %\renewcommand{\afterpartskip}{\vfil\newpage}
        \MakePerPage{footnoteA}
        \renewcommand*{\thefootnoteA}{(\roman{footnoteA})}
        \setmainfont{Dejavu Serif}
        \fnpos{critical-familiar}
        \linenummargin{outer}
        \lineation{page}
        \sidenotemargin{inner}
        %\let\footnoteruleA=\footnoterule
        \usepackage{bibleref}
        \Xparindent
        \Xafterrule[A]{0pt}  % n
        \Xbhooknote[A]{\vskip 0pt\noindent} 
        \Xinplaceoflemmaseparator{0pt}
        \Xlemmadisablefontselection{}
        \Xarrangement{paragraph}
        \arrangementX{paragraph}


        \Xlemmafont{}
        %\Xendlemmafont{\bfseries}

        \renewcommand\footnoteruleA{ %
            \kern-3pt \hrule width 5.5cm \kern 2.6pt
        }
        \renewcommand\Afootnoterule{ %
            \kern-3pt \hrule width 3.5cm \kern 2.6pt
        }
        \setlength{\linenumsep}{16pt}
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \MakePerPage{footnote@typeset}
        \MakePerPage{footnoteA@typeset}
        \MakePerPage{footnoteB@typeset}
        \AtEveryPend{\par\medskip} 
        \usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

        \usepackage[bookmarks, unicode]{hyperref}

        \makeindex
        \makeindex[title=Bible index,name=bible]
        \renewcommand{\biblerefindex}{\edindex[bible]}
        \begin{document}
        \chapter{Test chapter}
            \beginnumbering
            \pstart
            \lipsum[1]
        Testing Bible referencing\footnoteA{\ibibleverse{Matthew}(12:1)} 
        \lipsum[1]
        \pend

            \pstart 
        \lipsum[1]


            An old testament reference \footnoteA{\ibibleverse{Gn}(1:1-10)}.\\
            An old testament reference \footnoteA{\ibibleverse{Gn}(3:1-10)}.\\
            An old testament reference \footnoteA{\ibibleverse{Gn}(4:1-10)}.\\
            An old testament reference \footnoteA{\ibibleverse{Ex}(1:1-10)}.\\
            An old testament reference \footnoteA{\ibibleverse{Lv}(1:1-10)}.\\
            \lipsum[1]
            \pend
            \endnumbering

            \backmatter
            \printindex[bible]
        \end{document}
```

[image]

For sample output see picture above. Index shows line number 22. What i want is line number 16 (where footnote refers).. Yes , i can use familiar 'index ' command, but i'll loose line number and for many biblerefs is will be hard to find reference.

Comment: I can use ledsidenotes, but....question remains

Comment: the lastest version of indextools provides "notesnumber" option to add the notes number. But it seems to bug with `\bibleref`. I am looking for it.

Comment: It's a problem with `\ibibleverse`. I am looking on it. https://github.com/maieul/indextools/issues/6

Comment: I have found a solution, but the solution could depend of some correction in bibleref-french. I send an email to Nicolas Talbot, and I will wait some days.

Comment: I am waiting for answer.

Comment: It seems reledmac problem 'Test\footnoteA{Test footnote\edindex[bible]{Lv!1:1-10}}' causes in index page footnotes line number. I was trying ro use 'sidenotes' package but it does not work with 'reledmac'.I can not have numbered 'sidenotes' in 'reldmac'? opening new question for this.

Comment: NOW! There is two differents problems here. One is a reledmac problem, the other one is a bibleref problem. 1) \edindex which indicated the last line number when using in a side or familiar footnote is indeed a reledmac problem. But that is a no sens to refer to the line number while you use familiar footnote. You should refer to the note number. 2) indextools + reledmac allow us to refer to the footnote number. BUT here there is a bug with bibleref. See the MWE on github linked below.

Comment: SO for the resolution of the two problems 1) open an issue on github reledmac page. 2) wait just a little time I have an answer from the bibleref maintener.

Comment: I added "notenumber,innote" option to indextools call and \edindex in footnote gives same (lastpagenumber in index)

Comment: 1) Use OR innote OR notenumber, but not twice 2) Use \index in this case 3) I told you there was a bug index \ibibleverse. So please WAIT 1) I fix the bug in \ibibleverse 2) I send you a full answer.

Comment: Ok, there was also bug in indextools, and still a bug on reledmac. I am looking on.

Comment: So I open the issue https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/489 https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/490 and https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/491. Please let me time to solve them.

Comment: also this bug https://github.com/maieul/indextools/issues/9

Comment: Ok, I see now..I will wait fixies :) ..I found work around: 1) Introduce counter for Bfootnote to find easily bibleref on the page(because original text has quoted some bible passage and I add this information in separate notes(before it was usual footnote series A)). 2) use empty 'edtext` and empty 'lemma` 3) Use ibibleverse inside `Bfootnote'..This works somehow :)

Comment: I will try to fix this bug next week-end, but I can't tell you I am sure. I am quite busy.

Comment: Any news? and 6 chars to go :)

Comment: sorry, still very busy :-( maybe this week-end, but not sur at all. I need time for myself.

Comment: For now, I have finish to write my dissertation, so I can look on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 2.16.0, just send on CTAN, solves the problem:

- `\edindex` in familiar footnote refer to the position where the footnote are are called
- the "notenumber" option of indextools works.
- However, you should use version 1.16 of bibleref and add this line on your preamble `\renewcommand{\bvidxpgformat}{}`

Comment: Bibleref line number appears correctly in index now, But there is one minor problem in footnotes i get 1,2,3 instead of (i),(ii),(iii)

Comment: hum, I have to look on it

Comment: I have just send ton CTAN a version 2.16.1 which solves this problem.

Comment: but please, next time you have what is manifestly a bug of reledmac, use the normal way and open an issue on https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues