# reledmac and xindy

Tags: indexing, xindy, reledmac

Here is a code with `makeindex` [reledmac, bibleref entry in footnoteA and line number in Index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286752/reledmac-bibleref-entry-in-footnotea-and-line-number-in-index)

Since I have a Non English text I tried to make indexes with `xindy`

MNWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,14pt,onecolumn,openright ,a4paper]{memoir}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{xunicode}

    \usepackage[nonewpage,xindy]{indextools}
    \usepackage[series={A,B,C,D,E},xindy+hyperref]{reledmac} \usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{perpage}
    \MakePerPage{footnoteA}
    \renewcommand*{\thefootnoteA}{(\roman{footnoteA})}
    \setmainfont{Sylfaen}
    \fnpos{critical-familiar}
    \linenummargin{outer}
    \lineation{page}
    \sidenotemargin{inner}
    \usepackage{bibleref}
    \Xparindent
    \Xafterrule[A]{0pt}  % n
    \Xbhooknote[A]{\vskip 0pt\noindent} 
    \Xinplaceoflemmaseparator{0pt}
    \Xlemmadisablefontselection{}
    \Xarrangement{paragraph}
    \arrangementX{paragraph}
    \Xlemmafont{}

    \renewcommand\footnoteruleA{ %
        \kern-3pt \hrule width 5.5cm \kern 2.6pt
    }
    \renewcommand\Afootnoterule{ %
        \kern-3pt \hrule width 3.5cm \kern 2.6pt
    }
    \setlength{\linenumsep}{16pt}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \MakePerPage{footnote@typeset}
    \MakePerPage{footnoteA@typeset}
    \MakePerPage{footnoteB@typeset}
    \AtEveryPend{\par\medskip} 
    \usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}


            \newcounter{asidenote}
        \newcommand{\mysidenote}[1]{%
         \refstepcounter{asidenote}\textsuperscript{\alph{asidenote}}%
        \ledsidenote{\textsuperscript{\alph{asidenote}}\scriptsize#1}}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \rightnoteupfalse
    \leftnoteupfalse 
    \makeindex
    \makeindex[title=Bible index,name=bible]
    \renewcommand{\biblerefindex}{\edindex[bible]}
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{Test chapter}
        \beginnumbering
        \pstart
        \lipsum[1]
        An old\mysidenote{\ibibleverse{Gn}(1:1-10)} testament reference %\footnoteA{\ibibleverse{Gn}(1:1-10)}.\\
        An old testament reference \footnoteA{\ibibleverse{Gn}(3:1-10)}.\\
        An old testament reference \footnoteA{\ibibleverse{Gn}(4:1-10)}.\\
        An old testament reference \footnoteA{\ibibleverse{Ex}(1:1-10)}.\\
        An old testament reference \footnoteA{\edindex[bible]{Lv!1:1-10}}.
        \pend

        \endnumbering
            \backmatter
            \printindex[bible]

    \end{document}
```

Running command:

```
xindy -I xelatex -M texindy -M reledmac.xdy  -o bible.ind bible.idx
```

gives:

```
    WARNING: unknown cross-reference-class `ledinnote[$&2]'! (ignored)
```

and index page is empty.
So I need to write xdy file. How?
And another small question is How to have `pagenumber^{line number}`(linenumber as superscript) Instead of default `pagenumber(linenumber)` in index entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hum, maybe the handbook is unclear, but here are the following steps to get what you need.

1. The `xindy+hyperref` option doesn't replace the `xindy` options. So you need to replace

   \usepackage[series={A,B,C,D,E},xindy+hyperref]{reledmac}
   by 
   \usepackage[series={A,B,C,D,E},xindy,xindy+hyperref]{reledmac}
2. There is a `reledmac.xdy`file provided by in the `examples` folder of the reledmac handbook: http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/examples/reledmac.xdy. You just need to recopy it along your .tex file
3. opening it, you will find the lines

   (markup-locref-list  :open " (" :sep ", " :close ")"
                          :depth 1  :class "eledmac")
   Just changes them to

   (markup-locref-list  :open "\textsuperscript{" :sep ", " :close "}"
                          :depth 1  :class "eledmac")
   to get line number in superscript
4. At the end of the file, you have also some lines to be uncommented to work with hyperref.

Comment: Thank you very much.... and One more question please. For makeindex we can change behavior of index levels. Like level 1 `subitem` and level 2 `subsubitem`... I actually want to remove/change `subitem` on level 1 replacing it by `\---`..how can I do this with `xindy`?

Comment: `(markup-indexentry :open  "\---"
                     :close "" 
                     :depth 0)`

Comment: but that is not a reledmac problem…

Comment: Ok...thanks..Yes i know. Just did not want to open new question for this :)